# resend_on_timeout seems to be ignored by Ejabberd

Tags: configuration, yaml, ejabberd, stream-management

I'm new to Ejabberd and I've been trying to configure it so that it is robust to connection losses following those recommendations: [Dead connections, message loss, and outdated presence](https://www.ejabberd.im/faq/tcp)
Stream management is activated by default (I use ejabberd 15.07), I set resend_on_timeout to true in ejabberd.yml:

```
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    resend_on_timeout: true
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls: true
    certfile: "/Applications/ejabberd-15.07/conf/server.pem"
```

and mod_offline is activated:

```
mod_offline: 
  access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
```

Furthermore, the admin web interface confirms that resend_on_timeout is set to true:

```
[{certfile,
  <<47, 65, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97,
    116, 105, 111, 110, 115, 47, 101,
    106, 97, 98, 98, 101, 114, 100, 45,
    49, 53, 46, 48, 55, 47, 99, 111,
    110, 102, 47, 115, 101, 114, 118,
    101, 114, 46, 112, 101, 109>>},
 {starttls, true}, {access, c2s},
 {shaper, c2s_shaper},
 {max_stanza_size, 65536},
 {resend_on_timeout, true}]
```

Unfortunately, the following scenario does not work as expected:

1. user_a and user_b connect to ejabberd
2. user_b tells ejabberd that he implements [XEP-0198: Stream Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html)
3. user_b looses his connection without properly disconnecting from Ejabberd
4. user_a sends the message "Test message" to user_b
5. Ejabberd detects that user_b did not acknowledge the message

   ```
   2015-09-04 00:30:49.869 [info] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_unacked_stanzas:2877 1 stanzas were not acknowledged by user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314
   ```
6. Ejabberd sends an error message to user_a instead of storing the message offline for user_b

   ```
   2015-09-04 00:30:49.870 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1901 Send XML on stream = <<"<message from='user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314' to='user_a@localhost/MacBook Air de Cyrille' type='error' id='8C843796-CD60-4111-8754-EBAE20A0D75E'><body>Test message</body>\n<html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;'><span style='font-family: &apos;Helvetica&apos;;font-size: 12px;'>Test message</span></body></html><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x>\n<active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></message>">>
   ```

(The full log is available at the end)

I'm sure I'm missing something but I could not find what.
Many thanks in advance for your help.

#### Full ejabberd log from step 4 to 6

`2015-09-04 00:30:19.862 [debug] <0.466.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:349 Received XML on stream = <<"Test message\nhttp://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im\">http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"  style=\"background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;\">Test message\nhttp://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates\"/>\n">>`

```
2015-09-04 00:30:19.862 [debug] <0.466.0>@shaper:update:120 State: {maxrate,1000,523.8875943484103,1441319395776490}, Size=477
M=323.1461223235512, I=24086.201
2015-09-04 00:30:19.863 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:323 route
    from {jid,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"id">>,<<"8C843796-CD60-4111-8754-EBAE20A0D75E">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Test message">>}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"html">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">>},{<<"style">>,<<"background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;">>}],[{xmlel,<<"span">>,[{<<"style">>,<<"font-family: 'Helvetica';font-size: 12px;">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"Test message">>}]}]}]},{xmlel,<<"x">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:x:event">>}],[{xmlel,<<"composing">>,[],[]}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]}]}
2015-09-04 00:30:19.863 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>},{<<...>>,...}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...},{xmlcdata,...},{...}|...]}
2015-09-04 00:30:19.864 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:447 session manager
    from {jid,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"to">>,<<"user"...>>},{<<"type">>,<<...>>},{<<...>>,...}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...},{xmlcdata,...},{...}|...]}
2015-09-04 00:30:19.864 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:565 sending to process <0.458.0>
2015-09-04 00:30:19.864 [debug] <0.456.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:prepare_response:917 OutPacket: [{xmlstreamelement,{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"from">>,<<"user_a@localhost/MacBook Air de Cyrille">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"id">>,<<"8C843796-CD60-4111-8754-EBAE20A0D75E">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Test message">>}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"html">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">>},{<<"style">>,<<"background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;">>}],[{xmlel,<<"span">>,[{<<"style">>,<<"font-family: 'Helvetica';font-size: 12px;">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"Test message">>}]}]}]},{xmlel,<<"x">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:x:event">>}],[{xmlel,<<"composing">>,[],[]}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]}]}}]
2015-09-04 00:30:19.865 [debug] <0.456.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:send_outpacket:1059  --- outgoing data --- 
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><message xmlns='jabber:client' from='user_a@localhost/MacBook Air de Cyrille' to='user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314' type='chat' id='8C843796-CD60-4111-8754-EBAE20A0D75E'><body>Test message</body>
<html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;'><span style='font-family: &apos;Helvetica&apos;;font-size: 12px;'>Test message</span></body></html><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x>
<active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/></message></body>
 --- END --- 
2015-09-04 00:30:30.178 [debug] <0.466.0>@ejabberd_receiver:process_data:349 Received XML on stream = <<"\r\n">>
2015-09-04 00:30:30.179 [debug] <0.466.0>@shaper:update:120 State: {maxrate,1000,271.84566900163605,1441319419862845}, Size=2
M=1.1573040463605986, I=10315.866
2015-09-04 00:30:49.865 [info] <0.457.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:handle_info:522 Session timeout. Closing the HTTP bind session: <<"4388150e84a2c3e491fb66d9ff77ae9b78492cde">>
2015-09-04 00:30:49.865 [debug] <0.457.0>@ejabberd_http_bind:terminate:558 terminate: Deleting session 4388150e84a2c3e491fb66d9ff77ae9b78492cde
2015-09-04 00:30:49.865 [info] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_c2s:terminate:1842 ({socket_state,ejabberd_http_bind,{http_bind,<0.457.0>,{{127,0,0,1},55272}},ejabberd_http_bind}) Close session for user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314
2015-09-04 00:30:49.866 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_pubsub:node_action:4118 node_action <<"pubsub.localhost">> <<"flat">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}]
2015-09-04 00:30:49.866 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_pubsub:node_call:4099 node_call <<"flat">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}]
2015-09-04 00:30:49.866 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_pubsub:node_action:4118 node_action <<"pubsub.localhost">> <<"hometree">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}]
2015-09-04 00:30:49.867 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_pubsub:node_call:4099 node_call <<"hometree">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}]
2015-09-04 00:30:49.867 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_pubsub:node_action:4118 node_action <<"pubsub.localhost">> <<"pep">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}]
2015-09-04 00:30:49.867 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_pubsub:node_call:4099 node_call <<"pep">> get_entity_affiliations [<<"pubsub.localhost">>,{<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}]
2015-09-04 00:30:49.867 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_carboncopy:disable:249 disabling for <<"user_b">>
2015-09-04 00:30:49.867 [debug] <0.458.0>@mod_shared_roster:unset_presence:1104 unset_presence for <<"user_b">> @ <<"localhost">> / <<"7952730381441319317654314">> -> <<>> (0 resources)
2015-09-04 00:30:49.868 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_router_multicast:do_route:193 route_multicast
    from user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314
    domain localhost
    destinations [<<"user_b@localhost">>]
    packet {xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"unavailable">>}],[]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.868 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:323 route
    from {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"unavailable">>}],[]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.868 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"unav"...>>}],[]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.869 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:447 session manager
    from {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"unav"...>>}],[]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.869 [info] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_unacked_stanzas:2877 1 stanzas were not acknowledged by user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314
2015-09-04 00:30:49.869 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_router:do_route:323 route
    from {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"error">>},{<<"to">>,<<"user_a@localhost/MacBook Air de Cyrille">>},{<<"from">>,<<"user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314">>},{<<"id">>,<<"8C843796-CD60-4111-8754-EBAE20A0D75E">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Test message">>}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"html">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">>},{<<"style">>,<<"background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;">>}],[{xmlel,<<"span">>,[{<<"style">>,<<"font-family: 'Helvetica';font-size: 12px;">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"Test message">>}]}]}]},{xmlel,<<"x">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"jabber:x:event">>}],[{xmlel,<<"composing">>,[],[]}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]},{xmlel,<<"error">>,[{<<"code">>,<<"503">>},{<<"type">>,<<"cancel">>}],[{xmlel,<<"service-unavailable">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">>}],[]}]}]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.870 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_local:do_route:296 local route
    from {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"erro"...>>},{<<"to">>,<<...>>},{<<...>>,...},{...}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...},{xmlcdata,...},{...}|...]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.870 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:447 session manager
    from {jid,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>,<<"user_b">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"7952730381441319317654314">>}
    to {jid,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>,<<"user_a">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"MacBook Air de Cyrille">>}
    packet {xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"erro"...>>},{<<"to">>,<<...>>},{<<...>>,...},{...}],[{xmlel,<<...>>,...},{xmlcdata,...},{...}|...]}
2015-09-04 00:30:49.870 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_sm:do_route:565 sending to process <0.467.0>
2015-09-04 00:30:49.870 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_c2s:send_text:1901 Send XML on stream = <<"<message from='user_b@localhost/7952730381441319317654314' to='user_a@localhost/MacBook Air de Cyrille' type='error' id='8C843796-CD60-4111-8754-EBAE20A0D75E'><body>Test message</body>\n<html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='background-color:#e9e9e9;color:#000000;'><span style='font-family: &apos;Helvetica&apos;;font-size: 12px;'>Test message</span></body></html><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x>\n<active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></message>">>
```

Comment: It seems to happen with Bosh. Does it behave properly with standard c2s connection ?

Comment: I am building a client with Strophe.js and it only allows Bosh connection unfortunately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You configured `resend_on_timeout` option on ejabberd c2s listener, but you seem to be using http-bind / Bosh listener.
It should work as expected if you set it up on your http bind listener.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it was a different ejabberd_c2s that was used by http bind. I tried to add send_on_timeout:true as an option of  listener "port: 5280 module: ejabberd_http send_on_timeout: true" but it did not work neither. Where should I put the options of the ejabberd_c2s instance used by http_bind?

Comment: I think I found the answer. The last commit to ejabberd should solve my issue: [Pass stream management options defined in http listener to http-bind and web socket](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/f56a9e400dd1857484c9898f0b746f0a44ad2ac8) and it should work with the next release of ejabberd. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, we made the patch based on our discussion :)

Comment: Cool that's great news! Thanks a lot for your help!